# Crystal Reports version 11.5.3700.0 and 11.5.3300.0 cannot locate it in Visual Studio to install?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Below is the XML from the web.config file:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

Target Framework is 2.0 I am building this with VS 2010 on WIN 7.
But the issue here is that I installed how do I get the Crystal Reports component with the above version?  I heard that VS 2005 installs the above version 11.5... So I tried installing the Crystal Reports from Visual Studio 2005. But it only installed 10.2 version. I then tried installing  Crystal Reports VS 2008 but that installed  version 10.5. I am not able to find a source from where I can install 11.5.3700.0 and 11.5.3300.0 version. I also tried installing the Crystal Reports version 11, 11.5 etc with the hope that they will have the version i need. But I do'nt see the above version I need in my Global Assembly Cache. Its a client requirement and I cannot upgrade the Crystal Reports DLL. Can you tell me what component I need to install with Visual Studio 2010 that will give me the version DLL that i need. ?

Answer (score 1):

Even i was facing the same problem, but now i am able to solve it.
 You just have to install the CRforVS_13_0_5.exe compatible with the Service pack version and also the version of the Visual Studio. Refer to the location of the DLL and your application will stop giving error.

Regards 
Anks

Answer (score 0):

That's true, CR 11.5 R2 assemblies 11.5.3300 (.NET 1.1) and 11.5.3700 (.NET 2.0) are not supported on new VS2010, it has new CR assemblies, numbers starts with 13.0.....

You can see [Old CR SAP WIKI](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+2008+(and+9.1,+XI+R1,+XI+R2)+-+Version+and+Download+information+for+Service+Packs?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com) or [New CR SAP WIKI](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads).